# Video Upload to youtube from app

Tags: ios, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-iframe-api

I want to upload the recorded video from ios app directly to youtube on the click of a button.For this I tried some third party libraries like:
https://github.com/youtube/yt-direct-lite-iOS
https://github.com/NSRover/YouTube-API-Demo

but both are around 3 years old and shows a lot of missing files even in the sample code.
One after the other files are getting missing.
Is there any other way to do this out. Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may check these tutorials:

- [YOUTUBE API ON IOS : UPLOADING A VIDEO](https://nsrover.wordpress.com/2014/04/23/youtube-api-on-ios/)
- [Upload Videos to YouTube with iPhone custom App](http://urinieto.com/2010/10/upload-videos-to-youtube-with-iphone-custom-app/)

Basically, you need to:

- Create a iOS project in Xcode.
- Register an App with Google.
- Get the YouTube Data API.
- Integrate the API into your project.
- Configure the API for your Google App.
- Use the API to get Playlist data and upload a video.

Also check the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert) regarding `Videos: insert` method to upload a video to YouTube.

Answer (score 0):

I have made sample code for upload video from App to Youtube. Here is the link
https://github.com/maniyarpayal/youtubetest