# iOS: Share video to youtube in my app

Tags: ios, youtube-api, share

I am currently writing a plugin that uploads videos recorded by unity to youtube.

In case of Android, I can call Youtube's video upload UI using an intent. Is there only a direct way to upload via the data API in iOS? I would like to call up the video upload UI like Android on iOS or pass the video to YouTube application directly.

What kind of ways are there? it's possible implement it?

I need your help. thank you.

Comment: You can user google data API, to directly upload video to youtube in ios. http://www.ongraph.com/youtube-api-for-ios-uploading-a-video/

Comment: @D B Thanks for your comment. I read that too. but 'google-api-objectivec-client' is deprecated according to google. I want to know new way.

Answer (score 1):

Check the [Upload a video](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/implementation/videos#videos-upload) guide from Youtube API. You'll be using the [videos.insert](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert).

[Additional reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42037785/6577242).

We will need the Google Data API Client for Objective-C, and install it into our application. Here are the steps to do so:

1. Download the GData Client for Objective-C from here
2. Open the GData project with XCode
3. Drag and drop the group GData Source from the GData project into your project (reference it or copy it into your project directory, up to you)
   – Optional: In your project delete all groups inside GData Source but YouTube and Commons. This will make the compilation process much faster. You will have to comment the imports in your GData.h
4. Add the Security.framework into your frameworks
5. In the properties of your target, add the -ObjC to your Other Linker Flags setting
6. In the properties of your target, add the /usr/include/libxml2 path to your Header Search Path setting
7. Make sure your C Language Dialect is c99 in your target properties
   You should now be able to compile the API within your own app.
8. Next step is to go here to get a Developer Key from Google. Your Developer Key and Client ID are required in order to use the GData API.

Once you have them, take a look at the simple YouTube upload test sample code based on the Mac OSX Example inside the GData Client Objective-C code and add them there in the `YouTubeTestViewController.m`.